# git repo sync with another group

Tags: repo

Is it possible call  **repo sync** with specific another **gruop**

eg:

```
repo init -u git@$1.1.1.1/xyz.git -g A
repo sync
```

after synced, I will like to add another group **B** in **manifest.xml**
then I would like to test the group **B**, such as

```
repo sync -g B   <== repo sync seems not not support option **B**
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you must rerun `repo init` with group B in the same directory.

```
repo init -u git@$1.1.1.1/xyz.git -g B
repo sync
```